# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable on a closed interval $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then $f$ is Lipschitz on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis

I am wondering whether my proof is correct - this is from Abbot *Understanding Analysis*, exercise 5.3.1.

*Proof:* I will use indirect proof here. Suppose toward contradiction that $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $f$ is not Lipschitz on $[a,b]$. Then for all $M > 0$, there exists a pair of numbers $t, c$ in $[a,b]$ with $t \neq c$ such that
$$
\left|\frac{f(t) - f(c)}{t - c}\right| > M. 
$$

Letting $M'$ be an arbitrary but fixed positive real number and taking $\lim_{t \rightarrow c}$ on both sides of the above inequality yields $f'(c) > M'$, as $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$. Well, $f'(c)$, being a functional limit, is equal to some real number. So we have derived that there exists a real number that is greater than any arbitrary but fixed real number, contradicting the archimedian principle. $\rightarrow\leftarrow$

Thus, our assumption was wrong. That is, if  $f$ is differentiable on $[a,b]$ and $f'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ then $f$ is Lipschitz on $[a,b]$.

Comment: I feel slightly hesitant about this proof because the contradiction does not at all rely on the condition that $f'$ is continuous

Comment: $'$ just needs to be bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proof unfortunately does not work, since if you assume $f$ is not Lipschitz, that only gives you, for each $M$, a fixed pair $c,t$ with
$$\left|\frac{f(t) - f(c)}{t - c}\right| > M.$$
The preceding inequality need not hold once you vary the value of $t$, so you cannot take a limit.

What you can do, however, is directly observe that from the mean value theorem, there is some $d\in (c,t)$ with $$\left|f'(d)\right|=\left|\frac{f(t) - f(c)}{t - c}\right| >M,$$
and since this holds for arbitrary $M$, $f'$ must be unbounded on $[a,b]$, contradicting the continuity of $f'$.

##### Remark

This argument really doesn't need to be by contradiction, as one can equivalently argue directly that since $f'$ is continuous (and $[a,b]$ is compact), $f'$ is bounded in absolute value on $[a,b]$ by some $M$, and then by the mean value theorem we have for each $c,t\in [a,b]$, there is some $d\in(c,t)$ with
$$\left|\frac{f(t) - f(c)}{t - c}\right| =|f'(d)|\leq M,$$ hence $f$ is $M$-Lipschitz on $[a,b]$.

Note also that we only used continuity of $f'$ to show that $f'$ is bounded, so as per copper.hat's comment we could begin with the weaker assumption that $f'$ is bounded and the result still holds.